# symbol's function definition is void: incf (common lisp function in emacs24)

Tags: elisp, common-lisp, emacs24, pep8

I have download a emacs package for to format python codes with autopep8.

This package is named py-autopep8

[this is the lisp code](https://github.com/paetzke/py-autopep8.el/blob/master/py-autopep8.el)

can you se in the line number 78 this common lisp function

```
(incf line-offset len)
```

then, when I open emacs24 and I want to save the buffer I have this in the emacs shell

**Symbol's function definiton is void: incf**

Anybody know how to fix this error, therefore, to get the common lisp definitions in emacs lips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard Common Lisp functions are implemented in the `cl` package, so you could put:

```
(require 'cl)
```

in your init file.

More precisely, `cl-incf` is implemented in `cl-lib` and the `cl` package aliases `incf` to `cl-incf`.

Best practice would be for the package author to require `cl-lib` and use `cl-incf`; the `cl-lib` forms are preferred because they're isolated in their own namespace.